# javascript regex matches the second instead of the first space

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the following javascript regexes to find a pattern in a string containing html.

```
sHTML = sHTML.replace(new RegExp("td>" + sFindPhrase + "[^\'\"\\\/\>\<]* ", "gi"), "<span id='spanFnd'></span><span style='background-color: orange'>$&######");
sHTML = sHTML.replace(new RegExp("[^\'\"\\\/\>\<]" + sFindPhrase + "[^\'\"\\\/\>\<]* ", "gi"), "<span id='spanFnd'></span><span style='background-color: orange'>$&######");
```

so if sHTML is:

```
<td>brou ha ha </td><td>John May lives&nbsp;</td><td> blablabla</td>
```

and the user has typed **Jo**
shouldn't it match the whole **John** substring? But it matches **John May**. That is it goes to the second space character it finds in the string, it doesn't stop to the first. Why and how can I solve this ?

Thank you in advance.

**For those who have downvoted my question: it doesn't matter if the string contains html or plain text. Even with plain text it still doesn't work as it should.**

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: @Biffen, it doesn't matter, even if the string contains plain text, it still doesn't work as it should. Just tried it out.

Comment: @Jonny5 if I do that it matches to the end of the string.

Comment: Can you just edit, what exactly should be matched. Only `John` ?

Comment: Tried to make it lazy by putting a `?` after the `*` quantifier? `*? `

Comment: @Jonny5 it works flawlessly. Thanks alot!

Comment: If you didn't want the space to be matched, put it in the negative character class `[^\'\"\\\/\>\< ]*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make it lazy, by putting a `?` after the `*` [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

`[^\'\"\\\/><]*?[ ]`

[Test at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/aK0bS2/2)